# Why do animals die?

Tags: genesis

So humans die as punishment due to Adam and Eve eating the forbidden fruit.

But why do animals die?

I assume animals were created to be immortal originally as Adam was naming them in the Garden of Eden

Comment: Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site which is _hermeneutic_. Without a focus on specific text of scripture, we have nothing to analyse. The site does not discuss or debate topics as such (even though they be biblical in origin).  'Eating forbidden fruit' is clearly symbolic of spiritual activity.

Comment: When mankind sinned, the entire earth came under a curse.  See Gen 3 where the animals are cursed as well as the ground.  Part of the plan of salvation is to remove the curse, see rom 8:22